# Python's list comprehension: Modify list elements if a certain value occurs

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I do the following in Python's list comprehension?

```
nums = [1,1,0,1,1]
oFlag = 1
res = []
for x in nums:
    if x == 0:
        oFlag = 0
    res.append(oFlag)
print(res)

# Output: [1,1,0,0,0]
```

Essentially in this example, zero out the rest of the list once a `0` occurs.

Comment: Not every loop is amenable to replacement by a list comprehension.

Comment: Why don't you just search for the first `0`, slice your list and extend it with zeros to match the original size? Should be considerably faster, too.

Comment: Why do you need this done with a list comprehension?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and solutions!! @chepner I found my original method unnecessarily lengthy for the simple(?) task... List comprehension or not, welcome any simpler methods~

Comment: @zwer Nice! Thanks!

Comment: @ZoeL your approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'll go for @zwer approach (if you don't want to use numpy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nums = [1,1,0,1,1]
[int(all(nums[:i+1])) for i in range(len(nums))]
```

This steps through the list, applying the `all` operator to the entire sub-list up to that point.

Output:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Granted, this is **O(n^2)**, but it gets the job done.

Even more effective is simply to find the index of the first 0.
Make a new list made of that many `1`s, padded with the appropriate quantity of zeros.

```
if 0 in nums:
    idx = nums.index(0)
    new_list = [1] * idx + [0] * (len(nums) - idx)
```

... or if the original list can contain elements other than 0 and 1, copy the list that far rather than repeating `1`s:

```
    new_list = nums[:idx] + [0] * (len(nums) - idx)
```

Comment: I had the slicing idea too but then what if 0 is not in the list?

Comment: You beat me to it. You even gave the O(n*n) warning. Nice.

Comment: @pault In that case, this dies with a ValueError.  Now fixed.

Comment: Thank you all for contributing! You guys are artists! I ended up applying the find&padding method, though I found the slicing idea very smart (O aside)! 

Answer (score 8):

Some context, a list comprehension is a sort of "imperative" syntax for the `map` and `filter` functions that exist in many functional programing languages. What you're trying to do is usually referred to as an `accumulate`, which is a slightly different operation. You can't implement an `accumulate` in terms of a `map` and `filter` except by using side effects. Python allows you have side effects in a list comprehension so it's definitely possible but list comprehensions with side effects are a little wonky. Here's how you could implement this using accumulate:

```
nums = [1,1,0,1,1]

def accumulator(last, cur):
    return 1 if (last == 1 and cur == 1) else 0

list(accumulate(nums, accumulator))
```

or in one line:

```
list(accumulate(nums, lambda last, cur: 1 if (last == 1 and cur == 1) else 0))
```

Of course there are several ways to do this using an external state and a list comprehension with side effects. Here's an example, it's a bit verbose but very explicit about how state is being manipulated:

```
class MyState:
    def __init__(self, initial_state):
        self.state = initial_state
    def getNext(self, cur):
        self.state = accumulator(self.state, cur)
        return self.state

mystate = MyState(1)
[mystate.getNext(x) for x in nums]
```

Answer (score 5):

I had an answer using list comprehension, but @Prune beat me to it. It was really just a cautionary tail, showing how it would be done while making an argument against that approach.

Here's an alternative approach that might fit your needs:

```
import itertools
import operator

nums = [1,1,0,1,1]
res = itertools.accumulate(nums, operator.and_)
```

In this case `res` is an iterable. If you need a list, then

```
res = list(itertools.accumulate(nums, operator.and_))
```

Let's break this down. The `accumulate()` function can be used to generate a running total, or 'accumulated sums'. If only one argument is passed the default function is addition. Here we pass in operator.and_. The `operator` module exports a set of efficient functions corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python. When an accumulated `and` is run on a list of 0's and 1's the result is a list that has 1's up till the first 0 is found, then all 0's after.

Of course we're not limited to using functions defined in the `operator` module. You can use any function that accepts 2 parameters of the type of the elements in the first parameter (and probably returns the same type). You can get creative, but here I'll keep it simple and just implement `and`:

```
import itertools

nums = [1,1,0,1,1]
res = itertools.accumulate(nums, lambda a, b: a and b)
```

Note: using operator.and_ probably runs faster. Here we're just providing an example using the lambda syntax.

While a list comprehension is not used, to me it has a similar feel. It fits in one line and isn't too hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

For a list comprehension approach, you could use `index` with `enumerate`:

```
firstIndex = nums.index(0) if 0 in nums else -1
[1 if i < firstIndex else 0 for i, x in enumerate(nums)]
```

Another approach using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.cumprod(np.array(nums) != 0).tolist())
#[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here we take the convert `nums` to a numpy array and check to see if the values are not equal to 0. We then take the cumulative product of the array, knowing that once a 0 is found we will multiply by 0 from that point forward.

Comment: That's cool! `enumerate` is probably an overkill though, `range` should suffice. For bonus golfiness, cast the if condition to int.

Comment: @Norrius yes, I first understood the question as wanting to keep the original values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a linear-time solution that doesn't mutate global state, doesn't require any other iterators except the `nums`, and that does what you want, albeit requiring some auxiliary data-structures, and using a seriously hacky list-comprehension:

```
>>> nums = [1,1,0,1,1]
>>> [f for f, ns in [(1, nums)] for n in ns for f in [f & (n==1)]]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Don't use this. Use your original for-loop. It is more readable, and almost certainly faster. Don't strive to put everything in a list-comprehension. Strive to make your code simple, readable, and maintainable, which your code already was, and the above code is not.